# How to create jQuery like object functions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on trying to create a small library of helper functions for a project.

At the moment, I've setup a lot of functions in global scope that look like this:

```
function addClass(el, className) {
   el.classList.add(className);
}

var target = document.querySelector('.target);
addClass(target, "added-class");
```

With adding a class as an example, I'd like to follow a jQuery like function so that it gets called like this:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.target);
target.addClass("added-class");
```

How can I setup a function so that it is called this way?

Comment: If you want a jQuery like method, study the jQuery source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could extend [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)**

As @charlietfl mentioned, *extending native API works fine in theory but should also be concerned that future specifications in HTMLElement could add similar methods that open the app up to potential collisions.*

Like this example:

```js
function addClass(className) {
  this.classList.add(className);
}

// here you extends HTMLElement prototype
HTMLElement.prototype.addClass = addClass;


var target = document.getElementById('mydiv');
target.addClass('red');

var target2 = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
target2.addClass('blue');
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;  
}

.blue {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">HELLO</div>
<div id="mydiv2">WORLD</div>
```

**Or Could use a Wrapper**

Like this another example:

```js
function Element(id) {
  
  this.target = document.getElementById(id);  
  
  this.addClass = function (className) {
     this.target.classList.add(className);
  }

  return this;
}


var target =new Element('mydiv');
target.addClass('red');

var target2 =new Element('mydiv2');
target2.addClass('blue');
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;  
}

.blue {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">HELLO</div>
<div id="mydiv2">WORLD</div>
```

Comment: extending native API works fine in theory but should also be concerned that future specifications in HTMLElement could add similar methods that open the app up to potential collisions